# How to convert JSON to XML in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, json.net

I have objects such as :

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Installment { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to convert MyObject to XML with NewtonSoft.

I did not found directly convert an object to XML doc in NewtonSoft docs ([NwetonSOftDocs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm))

So I thought, I can first convert MyObject to JSON then I can convert to XML but it did not work.

Helper Class:

```
    public static XNode XmlSerialize<T>(T ToXml, string root, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        var ToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ToXml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, settings);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(ToJson, root);
    }

public static JsonSerializerSettings DefaultJsonSerializerSettings()
{
    return new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        
    };
}
```

I tested in Console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XNode xml = Helper.XmlSerialize<MyObject>(new MyObject{ Amount = "100", OrderId = "123123123", Installment="1", Products = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductName = "Test", Price = "100" }, new Product { ProductName = "Test2", Price = "200" } } }, "auth", Helper.DefaultJsonSerializerSettings());

            Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Output:

```
<auth>
  <orderId>123123123</orderId>
  <installment>1</installment>
  <amount>100</amount>
  <products>
    <productName>Test</productName>
    <price>100</price>
  </products>
  <products>
    <productName>Test2</productName>
    <price>200</price>
  </products>
</auth>
```

What i want :

```
<auth>
  <orderId>123123123</orderId>
  <installment>1</installment>
  <amount>100</amount>
  <products>
   <product>
    <productName>Test</productName>
    <price>100</price>
   </product>
   <product>
    <productName>Test2</productName>
    <price>200</price>
   </product>
  </products>
</auth>
```

I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: But why do your want it like this? first to JSON then to XML?

Comment: As the [Newtonsoft.Json documentation regarding its XML conversion feature](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) puts it next to the applied conversion rules: "_If the XML created from JSON doesn't match what you want, then you will need to convert it manually. The best approach to do this is to load your JSON into a LINQ to JSON object like JObject or JArray and then use LINQ to create an XDocument._". Well, you win some, you lose some...

Answer (score 0):

I always use [System.Xml.Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0)
. Is there any resctriction to not to use other libraries rather than NewtonSoft

```
    static public void Serialize<T>(string filePath, T obj)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            writer.Serialize(file, obj);
        }
    }

    static public void Deserialize<T>(string filePath, out T obj)
    {
        obj = default(T);
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) { throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath); }
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
        {
            obj = (T)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var sww = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sww) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
        {
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, obj);
            return sww.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```